# Eager loading 3 relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have these tables:

```
users | name - ... 
carts | user_id -  ... 
cart_product | cart_id -  product_id
```

relations:

```
Cart model
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
                ->withPivot('quantity','coupon_id')
                ->withTimestamps();
}

User model:
public function cart()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cart::class);
}
```

when i do the query there is n+1 in query like so:

```
auth()->user()->cart()->with('products')->products
```

How can I eager loading the query??

Comment: user()->with('cart.products')

Comment: What do you get if you print like this ```dd(auth())``` ? Let we know

Comment: @EncangCutbray the user that logged in!

Comment: Try like this ```return auth()->loadMissing('cart.products')``` let we know if you get an error

Comment: @EncangCutbray Call to undefined relationship [cart] on model [App\Models\Cart].

Comment: What do you get again if you print ```dd(auth()->cart)```

Comment: @EncangCutbray the cart that I store in DB

Comment: Oke next, debug again ```return auth()->loadMissing(cart)```,

Comment: @EncangCutbray `auth()` returns the AuthManager not a User

Comment: @EncangCutbray I dd like this  dd(auth()->user()->loadMissing('cart'));  I got the user and in relations section I got the cart  also!

Comment: Is this fixed your problem ?

Comment: @EncangCutbray Of course no, How can I get to products in cart ?

Comment: where is this N+1 issue you are referring to? ... I don't see any iterating happening here

Comment: Oke you got cart, next get the products ```return auth()->user()->loadMissing('cart.products')```

Comment: @lagbox when I get the products from cart by user I got N+1 for each product there is loop like product 1 loop and second another loop! in debggbar

Comment: @EncangCutbray man You right!! I use like this auth()->user()->loadMissing('cart')->cart; for cart and for product auth()->user()->loadMissing('cart.products')->cart->products; that's perfect one!

Comment: If you fixed your problem, please create a answer

Comment: @EncangCutbray please create  a answer to give you the correct mark cuz you answer worked for me

Comment: No, I can't. You must create the answer. Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you just want the products?

```
$products = auth()->user()->cart->products;
```

This will load the `cart` relationship then the `products` for that Cart. It will not run these queries more than once, as this `User` now has its `cart` relationship loaded (so it won't be loaded again when accessed via the dynamic property). That `Cart` has its `products` relationship loaded (which will not be loaded again when accessed via the dynamic property).

If you really feel like you want to "Lazy Load" these relationships (which you would have to see if the query is any different as it should just be the same as accessing it via the dynamic property) you can do that:

```
$products = auth()->user()->load('cart.products')->cart->products;
```

Comment: What the different between  load and loadMissing ? cuz the loadMissing is working but load does not!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

Comment: there doesn't appear to be a reason to need to do any lazy loading here, so not sure why you think you need to

Comment: because you were directly querying the relationship instead of using the dynamic property and you were doing some querying in a loop ... once you have that collection of products there is nothing to query again for unless you do the queries yourself

Comment: you do not call `load` in a loop ... once something is loaded it is loaded, why would you keep loading it over and over again?

Comment: I used it but the query still like in first image! but with loadMissing it's ok

Comment: this is why you should be using the first example from this answer as it loads all the relationships and will not load them again when accessed ... the fact that `loadMissing` is making a difference means you are doing things in a loop that you should not be doing

Comment: public function getCartProductsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->loadMissing('cart.products')->cart->products;
    }


the loop auth()->user()->CartProducts 

I do it like this!

Comment: exactly you should not be doing that, why would you try and load the same thing over and over again in a loop? and the method should be ` { return $this->cart->products; }` .... again there is no reason for Lazy Loading here; there is no N+1 issue that is even possible just by accessing the attributes of these models

Comment: side note: doing things this way you will have to make sure that every User has a Cart assigned to them or at least at this point this code is running they have to have a Cart

Comment: Humm.. Is there any other way to do it ? and forget to thank you sorry :) (Big thanks)